# Order of the cube of $\gamma + \mathcal{O}(\delta^2)$

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory, numerical-calculus

I know that $x = y  + \mathcal{O}(\eta^3)$. However, I also know that $\eta = \gamma + \mathcal{O}(\delta^2)$. What is the order of $x$?

My guess is that since $(a + b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3$ we should have something like
$$
x = y + \mathcal{O}((\gamma + \mathcal{O}(\delta^2))^3) \approx y + \mathcal{O}(\gamma^3) + \mathcal{O}(\gamma^2\delta^2) + \mathcal{O}(\gamma \delta^4) + \mathcal{O}(\delta^6) \approx y + \mathcal{O}(\delta^2)
$$
Is that correct?

Comment: With a $O$ usage, I prefer to see an "as" clause somewhere.  For example $x = y  + O(\eta^3)$ as $\eta \to \infty$.

Comment: @GEdgar  Oh good point! I mean as $\eta\to 0$

Comment: Well, if $\eta \to 0$, what about $\delta$?  What is $\gamma$?  Is it also a function that goes to zero?  If $\eta \to 0$ and $\delta \to 0$, then $\gamma$ cannot be a nonzero constant...